# Lost and Confused--Supplemental

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

I am advised to re-submit this as a separate question (had thought, initially, it was just an aside, barely worthy of mention); anyway, North & Hillard Ex. 195: "All order thus being lost, Nicias surrendered at discretion. He and Demosthenes, being condemned to death, died by poison;"

N&H give (Ans. Book): itaque confusis signis et ordinibus Nicias nullis conditionibus factis(footnote latis) se dedidit: qui cum Demosthene capitis damnatus veneno necatus est;"

Minor Q: any (significant) difference between using "factis"/ "latis"?

Main Q: deployment of "capitis": (N&H's English version takes no account of it) first thought it was "captis" so rushed into--they-having-been-captured; but, no: second instinct--of-the-head?! No! To Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict. displaying nineteen definitions of "captus", capitis". The only one that could be made to fit was--"of-the-capital-city" in the ancient and Medieval tradition of calling important people eg Fred-of-Freetown, wasn't entirely convinced so mentioned it, en passant, to Joonas. No!

Any thoughts?

Comment: original question: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/lost-and-confused

Answer (score 5):

The most likely solution seems to be that **capitis poena** means *capital/death penalty*, according to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaput), and **caput** in this context means *life [and death]*, and even *death [penalty]* by itself when accompanied by specific nouns:

[image]

If you see the third-to-last line, it even goes to quote an occurrence of **capitis damnare** meaning *to condemn to death*:

> postquam autem se **capitis damnatum** bonis publicatis audivit... ([Nep. Alc. 4.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Nep.%20Alc.%204.5&lang=original))
>   *But when he heard that he was **condemned to death***... ([Watson, 1886](http://www.tertullian.org/fathers/nepos.htm#p337))

Comment: thanks: so "capitis" means "of-the-capital (kind)"  as in (punishment) of the capital kind--death! And "of-the-capital-city" was nearly getting there--in roundabout ways.